# Style a multi-level menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a *Multi-Level* menu (with nested *Sub-Menu*) returned fom this *PHP* function:

> wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Category' ));

I'd like to add a *"first-level"* class to each of first level and a *"second-level"*  to each of seconnd level...and so on...

any help?

Comment: Have you checked out the codex? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Yes i have...it talks about parameters container_class, container_id, menu_class, menu_id...nothing about nested levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add your own classes because the HTML structure wp_nav_menu produces allows you to apply CSS to each level without the need for additional classes.

Here's a link giving a walk through;

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-wordpress-navigation-menus/

It has comments in the css that explains which levels the selectors are used for styling;

Comment: Here what i found out:

Wordpress back-end -> appareance -> menu

At top page click on label "Screen option" and thick checkbox: CSS class

This will add a field to "each item" of menu so you can add a custom class for each element.

Hope helps!

Comment: Yes, spot on! - that doesn't apply to levels though, that applies to specific links within the unordered lists generated. To style levels within the menu that link I posted will help.  Glad you are sorted though :)